# Emptying water out of a Conical Tank? (Calculus)?

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

Please help me with this Calculus question. I'm not asking you to do the whole thing, but I just need help setting up the height function. Here is the question:

A conical tank of radius $6$ feet and height of $15$ feet is $\frac{2}{3}$(of the height) filled with sea water. The tank is located on top of a water tower. The vertex of the cone is 100 ft above ground level (cone is inverted). Find the work required to pump all the water to a point 18ft above the ground. Seawater weights $64$$\frac{lbs}{ft^3}$.

I set up my graph with the cone's vertex at the origin, but I'm not sure if that is right. If so, would $h(x)=(-82+y)$?

I know that $A(x)=\pi(x)^2$ or more specifially $A(x)=(4\pi/15)*y$

When I finally set up my problem it looked like this:

Work$=64*(4pi/15)*(\int_0^{10} (-82y+y^2)dy)$

Which gives me an answer of $-121173.323$ ft/lbs of work, but I don't think that's right.

How do I set up the height function properly?

Comment: I edited the formatting of your post, click the edit button next to your post to know what i did so you can do it next time!

Comment: Hey thanks, but how to I make the integral from 0 to 10 instead of 0 to 1?

Comment: oh whoops sorry i will fix that for you now

Comment: Work is force times distance, force is mass times acceleration, and mass is volume times density.
Your formula is missing the acceleration (9.806 m/s^2 on Earth https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theoretical_gravity) as a factor. On the moon with a reduced acceleration the work would be smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of errors: as you suspected, the height isn’t quite right, but the cross-sectional area is also wrong.

The radius of the tank at height $y$ is $\frac25y$, so the cross-sectional area is $\frac{4\pi}{25}y^2$. To raise the cross-sectional slice of thickness $dy$ at height $y$ to the top of the tank, you must raise it $15-y$ feet, doing $$dW=64\cdot\frac{4\pi}{25}y^2(15-y)dy=\frac{256\pi}{25}(15y^2-y^3)dy$$ foot-pounds of work. Thus, it takes

$$\frac{256\pi}{25}\int_0^{10}(15y^2-y^3)dy$$

foot-pounds of work to raise all of the water to the top of the tank.

There are $64\cdot\frac13\cdot16\pi\cdot10=\frac{10240\pi}3$ pounds of water in the tank; they all fall a distance of $115-18=97$ feet after being raised to the top of the tank, doing $97\cdot\frac{10240\pi}3=\frac{993,280\pi}3$ foot-pounds of work in the process. Thus, the net work required is

$$\frac{256\pi}{25}\int_0^{10}(15y^2-y^3)dy-\frac{993,280\pi}3\text{ foot-pounds}\;.$$

You can of course set it up as a single integral: the slice at height $y$ is first raised $15-y$ feet and then dropped $97$ feet, so it is ‘raised’ a total of $15-y-97=-y-82$; your error was getting the wrong algebraic sign on $y$. If you do this, the answer is

$$\frac{256\pi}{25}\int_0^{10}(-y^3-82y^2)dy$$

foot-pounds.

Comment: @user97462: That’s exactly what I did: I just emptied it. I did **not** fill it. I **did** show you two ways to compute the answer; perhaps that’s the source of the confusion.

Comment: Ah yes I'm sorry, I'm used to the single integral method, which is why I didn't understand the first part, but now I get what you are saying.

Comment: @user97462: No harm done!