# Work required to empty the tank

Tags: calculus, integration

> A tank has the shape of an inverted circular cone with height 5 metres
>   and top radius 2 metres. It is filled with water to a height of 4 metres.
>   Find the work required to empty the tank by pumping all of the water to
>   the top of the tank.

$g=9.81\ \rm{ms}^{−2}$, and the density of water is $1000\ \rm{kg/m}^3$

*My working:*

$y=\frac25$, cross sectional area = $4π/25y^2$

$dW=1000×4π/25y^2(5-y)=160π(15y^2-y^3)dy$

$160π∫^{4}(15y^2-y^3)dy$

Not sure if this is it or there is more to it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: calculate the work needed for a disk at height h from the bottom of the tank, then do an integration

Comment: Maybe of interest http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507952/emptying-water-out-of-a-conical-tank-calculus?rq=1

Comment: We seem to be witnessing a fast and systematic externalization of OP's homework.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The work to (partially) empty the full tank by $h$ meters is given by

$$W(h)=gd\int_0^h h\,dV=gd\int_0^h h\left(1-\frac{h^2}{H^2}\right)S\,dh$$

which is the sum of the heights to be traversed by circular slices.